# Determining the pairs of integers that sum to some value in the array

Tags: algorithm

I have the program which counts the number of pairs of N integers that sum to `value`. To simplify the problem, assume also that the integers are distinct.

```
l.Sort();
for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; ++i)
{
     int j = l.BinarySearch(value - l[i]);
     if (j > i)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i + 1, j+1);
     }
}
```

To solve the problem, we sort the array (to enable binary search) and then, for every entry `a[i]` in the array, do a binary search for `value - a[i]`. If the result is an index `j` with `j > i`, we show this pair.

But this algorithm don't work on the following input:

`1 2 3 4 4 9 56 90` because `j` always smaller than `i`.

How to fix that?

Comment: Where in your input do you see pairs that sum up to 0?

Comment: It looks like he wants the pairs to sum to `value`, not necessarily 0.

Comment: @TomZych Yes, fixed it

Comment: `2 1 9 4 4 56 90 3` here integers are not distinct.

Comment: Why are you printing the (shifted) indices? Wouldn't it be more intuitive to print the values themselves?

Comment: @fl00r I know, so my question is how to fix this.

Comment: So `to assume or not to assume` that integers are distinct? It is two different problems to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with more efficient solution that needs more space.

Assume that numbers **are not distinct**

1. Create a hash table with your integers as a key and a frequency as a value
2. Iterate over this hash table.
3. For each key

   - calculate diff `diff = value - k`
   - lookup for `diff` in hash
   - if there is a match check if this value have got frequency > 0
   - if frequency is > 0 decrement it by 1 and yield current pair `k, diff`

Here is a Python code:

```
def count_pairs(arr, value):
  hsh = {}
  for k in arr:
    cnt = hsh.get(k, 0)
    hsh[k] = cnt + 1
  for k in arr:
    diff = value - k
    cnt = hsh.get(diff)
    if cnt > 0:
      hsh[k] -= 1
      print("Pair detected: " + str(k) + " and " + str(diff))

count_pairs([4, 2, 3, 4, 9, 1, 5, 4, 56, 90], 8)
#=> Pair detected: 4 and 4
#=> Pair detected: 3 and 5
#=> Pair detected: 4 and 4
#=> Pair detected: 4 and 4
```

As far as `counts the number of pairs` is very vague description, here you could see 4 distinct (by number's index) pairs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work for **non**-distinct values (which your
question does not say, but your comment implies), binary search only the
portion of the array after `i`. This also eliminates the need for the
`if (j > i)` test.

Would show the code, but I don't know how to specify such a slice in
whatever language you're using.